# Saving pdf file in internal storage with hide mode

Tags: android, file, storage, internal

I have requirement to save the pdf file to internal storage and the file should be **hidden**. It should not display to the user.

I have successfully saved my .pdf file in internal storage. But, I wanna to know that is it possible to save file by hiding it or in hidden mode ?

If yes, How ? I have already google out about this but, couldn't got any solution for such..thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving the pdf to Internal Storage, then it's only accessible by your app (which means pdf viewers can't view it). This essentially hides the file. Is this what you mean?

Comment: it should be a comment

Comment: @swerly, you are right. The user is not able to view it inside Gallary structure of device or from anywhere. But, it also should not display when User moves or open app internal folder structure. It will be visible to user when he/she will go to app folder structure. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.` as prefix of file to hide it with most browser but it is not real invisible (in Linux, I can `ctrl+H` to see hidden files like this).

I think you can follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) to make file *app-private*.

Answer (score 0):

For storing file as hidden in the internal storage you need to create a folder with "." prefix.This will make the folder hidden and doesnot show up in gallery or while scanning files.

```
File newdir = yourContext.getFilesDir() (".YourFolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!newdir.exists()) {
      newdir.mkdirs();
    }


File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".YourFolder");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
     mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
    }
```